# Exclude set of characters from regular expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression (in Java) to validate that a given `String` value must be in the following form:

- starts with 4 uppercase letters
- followed by 12 alphanumeric characters
- cannot include, at any time, the characters `0`, `1`, and `L`

This is what I've got so far: `^(?:(?![01L])[A-Z]{4}[A-Z0-9]{12})` ... but still, I cannot make it work.

Sample data:

```
SKDNCNSK8SD30DDD
SKDNCNSK8SD31DDD
SKDNCNSK8SD3IDDD // valid
SKDNCNSK8SD3LDDD
SKDNCNSK8SD3ODDD // valid
SKDNCNSK8SD3ADDD // valid
1234567890123456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic pattern is correct, but the negative lookahead you are using to restrict to not having `0`, `1`, and `L` is incorrect.  Try using this version:

```
^(?!.*[01L])[A-Z]{4}[A-Z0-9]{12}$
```

### Demo

The negative lookahead `(?!.*[01L])` says to assert that `[01L]` does not appear anywhere in the string.

Comment: Impressive...that was quick! Thank you!